# what if Poco StreamSocket.available() returns 0?

Tags: poco-libraries

What situation will the StreamSocket.available() return 0?

What should I do within that case? Should I close the connection, or just ignore it? There is guess that the system is really busy leading to 0 bytes returned to StreamSocket.

Comment: Is it used for checking whether the connection is closed?

Comment: BTW, the StreamSocket.available() is called in onReadable() function.

Comment: If you are using Reactor framework, and onReadable() callback is called, then there is some data to read and available() should not return 0.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do depends on the logic of your application. If available() returns 0 and you expect some data, it means it has not yet arrived and you may want to keep on inquiring or simply call receiveBytes() (which, if socket is in blocking mode, will block until data arrives). If receiveBytes() returns 0, then the remote end has closed or reset the connection and you should drop it, too.